# Why can't rspec find my no-params-required route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

### Background

I am trying to port an old `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` test to rspec.

This test is currently passing:

```
require 'test_helper'

class HeartbeatControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "heartbeat" do
    get "/heartbeat"
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

### Controller

I have a `HeartbeatController` which returns a 200:

```
class HeartbeatController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render(json: { 'status': 'ok' })
  end
end
```

It works fine with `curl`.

### Route

`rake routes` shows the route:

```
                               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                            heartbeat GET    /heartbeat(.:format)                                                                     heartbeat#show
```

### Spec

My test is pretty straightforward:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe HeartbeatController do
  it 'succeeds' do
    get '/heartbeat'
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

But when I run it

```
Failures:

  1) HeartbeatController succeeds
     Failure/Error: get '/heartbeat'

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/heartbeat", :controller=>"heartbeat"}
     # ./spec/controllers/heartbeat_controller_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00718 seconds (files took 1.11 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/heartbeat_controller_spec.rb:4 # HeartbeatController succeeds
```

### Questions

- Why is this test failing?
- What did I do wrong?
- How could I debug this further if Stack Overflow didn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a controller spec you want to pass the name of the method and not the route.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe HeartbeatController do
  it 'succeeds' do
    get :show
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

Controller specs don't actually drive the whole rails stack - they just create a mocked request and pass it to an instance of the controller and call the method on the controller.

The reason you are get a routing error is that `ActionController::TestCase::Behavior` tries to validate that a route exists for that given controller/method name combo. Thus `No route matches {:action=>"/heartbeat", :controller=>"heartbeat"}`.

This whole process of unit testing controllers is known to be highly flawed as you're mocking out huge portions of the framework and not actually testing what controllers do - they respond to HTTP requests. As the routing layer and middleware stack are mocked out your tests will not cover them as a real integration test would.

Both the [Rails and RSpec team discourage directly testing controllers](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs). Instead use [request specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) which actually drive the whole stack.

```
# spec/requests/heartbeats_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'Heartbeats', type: :request do
  describe "GET /heartbeat" do
    it 'succeeds' do
      get '/heartbeat'
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough and helpful answer. To get the replacement test you wrote working, I had to make two minor changes: `/heartbeats` to `/heartbeat`, and `be_success` to `be_successful`

Comment: @AaronBrager right. I was lazy and just copy pasted the controller spec with a few small changes. I always set up the generators to skip controller specs and generate request specs instead. Hopefully one day RSpec rails will catch up and not default to generating code thats discouraged by default.

Comment: Thank you! I had been banging my head wondering why my tests were not properly routing the requests. Switching to request specs did the trick :)